# Safari request caching with Axios

Tags: safari, axios, fetch

When making multiple simultaneous network requests to the same resource, Safari, seems to return a cached version of the response. This only seems to happen when using `Axios`. When using `fetch`, I get a fresh version of the response.

Disabling network caching from the network tab seems to fix the issue. No matter what headers I put into the request, I can’t get it to bypass the cache.

Chrome and Firefox don't seem to have the same issue.

Here is a small fiddle to demonstrate.

https://jsfiddle.net/67pbntcj/4/

[image: Console response]